Enquire an extension object field at runtime (when field's name is provided as string) with python opcua
I am trying to compare the live value of an extension object's field. But I do not know which field to compare unless the program is run i.e. name of the field to compare comes from an excel file.
My class structure looks like as shown in below image and I can read the data correctly from my Server which a PLC that can measure pressure.

The Variable to read from the PLC is READ_PCM_PR_I9_INFO which is of sPressureSensorInfo type structure which again consists of another structure physicalData which has the actual reading field readingMBar.
Since I can read the nodes and also parse the ExtensionObject with  typeDefinitions = client.load_type_definitions(), I have no issues populating the live sensor reading.
The problem I am trying to solve is to compare the field that comes from an excel file which reads the field's name as a string and labelled as READ_PCM_PR_I9_INFO.physicalData.readingMBar  which means that read readingMBar field from the variable READ_PCM_PR_I9_INFO as shown below

The test case above reads Check READ_PCM_PR_I9_INFO.physicalData.readingMBar is in the range 0 to 25.
So I have to iterate through the composite structure sPressureSensorInfo at runtime and reach the nested structure's readingMBar field and fetch the live reading then compare it to a value given in the excel file.
Is there a way to dynamically achieve this i.e. accessing the composite structure's inner field based on the label provided as string?

Referring below links
How to dynamically compose and access class attributes in Python? [duplicate]
Lexical cast from string to type
Getting attributes of a class
I managed to first split the different fields of READ_PCM_PR_I9_INFO.physicalData.readingMBar as below:
parameterFields = cmd.api.split('.')

where cmd.api fetches READ_PCM_PR_I9_INFO.physicalData.readingMBar string during the csv file read.
And then individually fetching the inner attributes as shown below gives me the nested field's value
 innerField = getattr(plcKeyValueList[parameterFields[0]], parameterFields[1])

 for i in range(2, len(parameterFields)):
   innerField = getattr(innerField, parameterFields[i])
 

where plcKeyValueList[parameterFields[0]] returns the object based on the parameterFields[0] node identifier. In this case, it is READ_PCM_PR_I9_INFO which is an object of sPressureSensorInfo type.
plcKeyValueList is a dictionary that I have created to get the live value of all the variable nodes (all the values from the plc) with the key being node identifier string.
We can also probe the type of the field as:
structureType = type(plcKeyValueList[parameterFields[0]])
                

Additional info, If we want to write the composite structure, we can create the dataValue as:
container = type(plcKeyValueList[parameterFields[0]])()
container.physicalData.readingMBar = 75
datavalue = ua.DataValue(ua.Variant(container, HALTypeDict[parameterFields[0]]))

where HALTypeDict maintains the type list with key being identifier string.
